# Error in code - Class names are only accepted if annotation

Tags: java, algorithm

I have question about my code which does the Hoare Partition Method.

Here is the pseudo-code: (please correct something if it's incorrect)

```
HOARE-PARTITION ( A, p, r)
 1 x ← A[ p]
 2 i ← p−1
 3 j ← r +1
 4 while TRUE
 5        do repeat j ← j − 1
 6        until A[ j ] ≤ x

 7        do repeat i ← i + 1
 8        until A[i] ≥ x

 9        if i < j
10             then exchange A[i] ↔ A[ j ]
11             else return j
```

And my code:

```
public class Hoare {
    public static  int partition(int a[],int p,int r) {
        int x = a[p];
        int i = p - 1;
        int j = r + 1;

        while (true) {    
            do
            {
                j = j - 1;
            } while(a[j] >= x);

            do
            {
                i = i + 1;
            } while(a[i] <= x);

            if (i < j) {
                int t = a[i];
                a[i] = a[j];
                a[j] = t;
            } else {    
                return j;
            }
        }        
    }

    public static void main(String[]args) {
        int a[] = {13, 19, 9, 5, 12, 8, 7, 4, 11, 2, 6, 21};
        partition(a, 0, a.length-1);
    }
}
```

And error is:

```
error: Class names, 'Hoare', are only accepted if annotation
processing is explicitly requested
1 error
```

Any ideas as to the cause?

Comment: Your question is poorly labeled, poorly titled (you don't want help with a partition algorithm you want help debugging) and your code is poorly formated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You seem to have translated:

```
do repeat stmt
until A[ j ] ≤ x;
```

into

```
do {
    stmt;
} while (A[j] >= x);
```

This is not correct.  The comparison which is the opposite of ≤ would be >, not ≥.  Therefore, your comparison when translating from "until" to "while" would use > such as `while (A[j] > x);`.

The other errors in your possible homework are similar and I encourage you to think each translation through carefully on your own.

Answer (score 1):

After re-formatting your question, I now see what you asked originally.  The answer to your question is found in the [Java Documentation](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/getStarted/problems/)

In your case, you need to use `javac Hoare.java` to compile.

```
Class names, 'HelloWorldApp', are only accepted if annotation processing is explicitly requested

If you receive this error, you forgot to include the .java suffix when compiling the program. Remember, the command is javac HelloWorldApp.java not javac HelloWorldApp.
```